# React Native Styled components dynamic font sizing

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components

Let's say i have a basic, base level StyledText component;

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

const StyledText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: pink;
`
export default StyledText
```

I then have an extension of that Text component that handles titles;

```
import StyledText from '../StyledText'

const StyledTitle = StyledText.extend`
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
`

export default StyledTitle
```

Simple so far.

What i need to do is dynamically increase the font size based on the size of the device. A simple function can handle this. But is there a way that the sizing function or util can only be called once from the main StyledText component, rather than repeated throughout the app with EVERY instance of StyledText extension?

Just to clarify, there is not a problem surrounding the logic of increasing the size, the problem is importing and using the util for every single use of any extended Text component.

For example, the util might look like this;

```
// utils
export function fontSize(size) {
  // do some logic here to increase the size, or whatever...
  return `
    font-size: ${size}px;
  `
}
```

Then used like this;

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { fontSize } from 'utils/StyledUtils'

const StyledText = styled.Text`
  ${fontSize(16)}
  color: pink;
`
export default StyledText
```

The problem is that the util file has to be imported and referenced all the way through the app.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/helpers/normalizeText.js) is not what you are looking for but maybe it will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks, but not really.. i have just edited to the question to expand on the problem.

Comment: I don't see your problem. The util file doesn't have to be imported and referenced all the way through the app. It only needs to be imported and referenced from within the `StyledText` module. You'll import StyledText and use that throughout your app, but you wouldn't also have to import the utils with it.

Comment: And then StyledText will be extended several times to make up the other text element; StyledTitle, StyledLabel etc etc. All of those will also need to import and use that util function - that's the scenario i am trying to avoid, but it doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem a while ago, and I solved it by creating an universal function that takes size as argument and returns new size that fits on different screen resolution. You can use this function for every size in your app.

Here is the function inside file responsive.js:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export const ResponsiveSize = (size) => {
    if(deviceHeight===568) { return size }
    else if(deviceHeight===667) size*1.17 
    else if(deviceHeight===736) size*1.29 
    else if(deviceHeight===1024) size*1.8 
}
```

Notice that size is multiplied by some fixed numbers (I did it for iOS devices) that you can modify to fit your needs.

Then you can style your text as following:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { ResponsiveSize } from './responsive'

const StyledText = styled.Text`
  font-size: ResponsiveSize(16);
  color: pink;
`
export default StyledText
```